# Azure AD get Information from Claim

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I use authentication with Azure AD B2C.

```
var Claims = User.Claims;
var ClientIdClaim = Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

gives me the Object-ID back. But I need also the user name. How I can access the username (marked yellow)?

[image]

Comment: Normally the username would be stored in the `Name` claim type. So you should find it using `var username = Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);`

Comment: It returns null

Comment: Did you test your policy using the "Run Now" link from the Azure Portal? If you configure the Reply URL of your application registration to https://jwt.ms, you will see the resulting token after using the "Run Now" link. Then you can determine if email is even being returned into your token. If not, you need to configure that first. That depends on if you are using Built in or Custom Policies.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the claim is returned to the application. Go to azure portal->your user flow policy->**Application claims**

[image]

Also, you can test your policy using the "Run Now" link from the Azure portal(just like @Jas Suri suggested).

[image]

You will be redirected to https://jwt.ms/.

[image]